# Parameterized Build - Multiple "instances" of a single parametrized job (a template) AKA fixed parametrized build

Tags: jenkins

Long story short,

I was wondering if anyone ever felt the need for (and knows of any implementation of) the possibility of "instantiating" (OO terminology) a parametrized build.

What I mean is treating a parametrized build as a template, from which many "instances" can be generated.
Each instance is supposed to define a different combination of values for the parameters.

The final goal is twofold:

1. DRY (which is given simply by the parametrized build concept)
2. having separate build histories / test reports for each instance (otherwise it would be a mess)
3. the instances would be schedulable directly in jenkins UI (while a parametrized build is not)

The template would then be used only for:

- manual builds
- changing the config for all of the instances at once

Now, time for some context, as I may be missing something in my overall approach.
You are welcome to point me in the right direction :)

I have a maven project with a suite of selenium tests that I want jenkins to run.
The suite is parametrized: browser, OS, test environment.
So, I can run it e.g. with `mvn test -Dbrowser=chrome -Dplatform=win [..]`.

I want a separate test report for each combination of my parameters.
As a newbie, my first solution was "Copy existing job".
Quick and dirty. But effective.
As you will know, problems arise when you need to make a change to the configuration of the job, and you want to keep in sync all of these copy&pasted jobs.
Then I found the parametrized build feature.
It's very cool (code reuse/maintainability++), but the test report and the build history is shared among all of the actual builds, therefore I can not rely on them for a tidy reporting like "this test is always failing on IE; but it isn't on chrome", and so on.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are describing is the [matrix](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) project

There are also selenium plugins, I put one together to work with matrix jobs https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Axis+Plugin

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be what I want. I'm reading "Jenknis the definitive guide" and it is clearly mentioned as the way to go when building jobs running web tests against multiple browsers/OSs. One lack I can see: you can't build a single combination, as the build btn is present only at the "top level". Is it correct? Also, I don't like the fact that it is implemented as a different type of project: I mean, it should be an option for every type of projects.

Answer (score 1):

> `One lack I can see: you can't build a single combination, as the build btn is present only at the "top level".`

Have you tried the Matrix Combination plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Combinations+Plugin